# subsetting a list column of integer matrices

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, unnest

#### Background

I've gotten myself into a situation where one column in a tibble/dataframe consists of a list of integer matrices which have zero or more rows and exactly 2 columns. This column happens to be the output of a `stringr::str_locate_all()` invocation, so I expect this is a common scenario.

What I would like to do is to select only one of the columns of the integer matrices and then unnest the dataframe, but I am getting confused about how to do this properly.

#### Example

Here's an example (*I have to create it manually because `dpasta()` doesn't seem to work with list column tibbles*). In any case, my starting point, is the tibble **mydf**:

```r
library(tidyverse)

m1 <- matrix( c(761,784),             nrow=1,ncol=2, dimnames = list(c(),c("start","end")) )
m2 <- matrix( integer(0),             nrow=0,ncol=2, dimnames = list(c(),c("start","end")) )
m3 <- matrix( c(1001,2300,1010,2310), nrow=2,ncol=2, dimnames = list(c(),c("start","end")) )

mydf <- tibble( item = c("a","b","c"), pos = list(m1,m2,m3))
```

Below is what that looks like in the rstudio viewer. *It's kind of misleading because it suggests that the pos rows are just vectors of integers. They're actually nx2 matrices and there isn't any cue that indicates it's more complex. It caused me some confusion, but that's beside the point now.*

[image: starting point]

What I would like to do is end up with an unnested tibble where the 1st column, "start", is selected. The desired output would look like this (after unnesting):

```r
mydf_desired <- tibble( item = c("a","c","c"), start_pos = c(761,1001,2300))
```

[image: desired outcome]

Note that the first row in mydf had only one row in it's pos matrix, so it has one row in the desired result. The row with item="b" had a 0x2 matrix, so it doesn't appear (but it would have been OK if it appeared as an NA too). The row with item="c" had two rows in the pos matrix, so it has two rows in the desired result.

#### What I tried

This seems simple enough, I've unnested list columns before. The only twist here is that I have to first select the "start" column and then unnest, right? I just `map` the pos list column to [,1] to pick off the 1st column (the "start" column). And then it should be a matter of unnesting...

```r
mydf_desired <- mydf %>% 
                mutate(start_pos = map(pos, ~ .[,1])) %>% 
                unnest()
#> Error in vec_rbind(!!!x, .ptype = ptype): Internal error in `vec_assign()`: `value` should have been recycled to fit `x`.
#> Warning: `cols` is now required.
#> Please use `cols = c(pos, start_pos)`
```

No idea what "`value should have been recycled to fit x`" actually means, but it's also giving me a warning about not giving cols in `unnest()`. The suspicion is now something about what I am giving `unnest()`.

If I omit `unnest()` I don't get that error...

```r
mydf_desired <- mydf %>% 
                mutate(start_pos = map(pos, ~ .[,1]))
```

And the output looks like this...

[image: before unnest]

That sort of looks OK, I notice there's still a pos entry for item=b of `integer(0)`. But even if I omit that row, I get the same error when I try to `unnest()`.

Here's where I am stumped. Why can't I just `unnest()` this tibble? What is the meaning of the `value should have been recycled to fit x` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes because `unnest` is trying to unnest `pos` column. You can specify which columns you want to `unnest` explicitly to avoid the error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mydf %>% mutate(start_pos = map(pos, ~.[, 1])) %>% unnest(start_pos)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  item  pos               start_pos
#  <chr> <list>                <dbl>
#1 a     <dbl[,2] [1 × 2]>       761
#2 c     <dbl[,2] [2 × 2]>      1001
#3 c     <dbl[,2] [2 × 2]>      2300
```

---

If you want `NA` for `"b"` item you can use `unnest_longer`

```
mydf %>% 
   mutate(start_pos = map(pos, ~.[, 1])) %>% 
   unnest_longer(start_pos, indices_include = FALSE)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  item  pos               start_pos
#  <chr> <list>                <dbl>
#1 a     <dbl[,2] [1 × 2]>       761
#2 b     <int[,2] [0 × 2]>        NA
#3 c     <dbl[,2] [2 × 2]>      1001
#4 c     <dbl[,2] [2 × 2]>      2300
```

Or `unnest` with `keep_empty = TRUE`.

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(start_pos = map(pos, ~.[, 1])) %>%
  unnest(start_pos, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets at the core screw-up I made. unnest() has some new features, and actually it makes more sense to explicitly indicate which col to unnest  rather than just rely on it to pick one (even if it's the only possible one).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `filter` the rows, then `map` over the `list` element and extract the column from the `matrix`, and use `unnest_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mydf %>% 
   filter(lengths(pos) > 0) %>%
   transmute(item, start_pos = map(pos, ~ as.vector(.x[,1]))) %>% 
   unnest_longer(c(start_pos))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  item  start_pos
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 a           761
#2 c          1001
#3 c          2300
```

---

Also, can avoid the `filter` step, if we convert to `tibble`

```
mydf %>%
   transmute(item, pos = map(pos, ~ .x[,1] %>%
                          tibble(start_pos = .))) %>%
   unnest(c(pos))
```

Comment: thanks, this really saves the day! I now see that nest_longer() seems to be relatively recent development (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/rectangle.html).